# How Do I Shut Off Visual Studio 2008 Script Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer, script-debugging

If I launch an ASP.NET project, using Visual Studio 2008 and Internet Explorer, Visual Studio starts script debugging. I get a Script Documents node with a child node of Windows Internet Explorer and Default.aspx with a bazillion anonymous code nodes underneath.

I'm having difficulty shutting this off, other than telling VS to launch the app in FireFox. I've searched around and found the solution to shut off script debugging in Internet Explorer, but this changed nothing for me.

Has any one found a solution?

Comment: I should have also clarified, I'm using Internet Explorer 8. 
Internet Options -> Advanced : Both Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer) and (Other) are checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is a known problem, and a possible fix is to install Silverlight Tools, I've decided the best solution is to ditch Internet Explorer 8 and just launch my sites in FireFox.

Answer (score 5):

Disable all script debugging:

- Open a new command prompt
  (start->run, cmd.exe). **If you are on
  a 64-bit computer this needs to be a
  32-bit prompt** (start->run,
  c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe)
- reg add
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2}
  /v ProgramProvider /d
  {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639}
  /f

If you are using Visual Web
   Developer Express, replace
   'VisualStudio' with 'VWDExpress':

- reg add
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2}
  /v ProgramProvider /d
  {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639}
  /f

If you want to restore your computer so that you can debug scripts again:

- reg add
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2}
  /v ProgramProvider /d
  {170EC3FC-4E80-40AB-A85A-55900C7C70DE}
  /f

Comment: This registry tricks works well for me VSTS 2008 SP1, IE8, Win7 32Bit

Comment: It only doesn't work because there is a typo in the registry key. It will work if you add a '\' between 'Engine' and '{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2}'.

Comment: I can confirm that this works.  In addition to the missing backslash, there's also an essential bit about using a 32-bit prompt.  I've taken the liberty of putting it in bold.  With those two essential pieces, this *does* work.

Comment: Well...I take that back.  This *partly* works, in that it doesn't show Script Documents anymore.  However, it doesn't actually prevent IE debugging.  Even if I have the IE options set to disable script debugging, and even if I tell it in the popup dialog to disable script debugging, the next time I run, it's still enabled again.  I'll have to try that Silverlight thing, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Did you check both boxes in IE to disable script debugging:

Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)

Disable Script Debugging (Other)

Also, make sure that after you made the change you closed all instances of IE. Then try debugging with VS again.

Update: just tried it myself and this solution does not work.

Update2: still does not work after a reboot

Finally found a possible solution [from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2009/04/06/disabling-script-debugging-in-vs-2008-ie8.aspx). Apparently this is a known issue and the workaround is to install the silverlight tools and tell the web project to debug silverlight (the debugger apparently cannot debug both silverlight and scripts).

Confirmed: The Silverlight tools solution does indeed work.

Comment: Ugg, install more product to fix other product. Good find on the article though. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help find the answer. This is one of those really frustating issues where things don't work they way they should. Great question!

Comment: does anybody know if installing the SL3 or SL4 tools has the same effect?

Comment: ok well I just tried it with the SL3 tools and seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly certain it's an IE option and that it requires a reboot.

Comment: You might need to restart IE but not reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, go to Internet Options -> Advanced tab, and check Disable Script Debugging ( Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 0):

In internet explorer:
Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced Tab -> Disable Script Debugging

[image: Internet Options Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking the file and selecting "View In Browser" to see if you get the same error? This method avoids the need to debug your code if you are certain that it is bug free of course.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio go to Tools > Options.
Make sure 'Show all settings' is checked.

[image: Visual Studio Tool Options]

It is in the Debugging section

Comment: Where is the Show All Settings flag? Couldn't find anything about disabling script debugging.

Comment: Ditto: I've never seen a "Show all settings" flag.  Using VS 2008 for Team Developers

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

This work around requires the Silverlight 2 Tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 to be installed. So if you don't have these tools installed, you can download them from Microsoft (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C22D6A7B-546F-4407-8EF6-D60C8EE221ED&displaylang=en). If this is not an option for you, there is some alternative work arounds at the bottom of this blog post. 
Right click on your project and open up project properties 
Go to the 'Start Options' sheet, and click the 'Silverlight' button at the bottom of the screen. Because the debugger cannot debug both Silverlight code and Script code at the same time, this will disable Script debugging and therefore avoid the problem.

http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2009/04/06/disabling-script-debugging-in-vs-2008-ie8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps for visual studio 2008

1)

```
32Bit: start->run, cmd.exe
64Bit: start->run, c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe
```

2)      Run this commands:

a.       to close:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f
```

b.      to open:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {170EC3FC-4E80-40AB-A85A-55900C7C70DE} /f
```

Answer (score 0):

The IE/ASP debugger was driving me nuts because it was literally taking minutes to start up an Office Add-in project.

"Disable Script Debugging" had no effect. Nor did the registry hack, and installing Silverlight tools is unpalatable at best, assuming it would work.

The answer is actually quite simple: in the Project Properties pane for the Web project, under the "Web" tab, go down to "Debuggers" and uncheck ASP.Net.

You may also find it helpful to start up with CTRL-F5, "Start without Debugging", which worked for my Office Add-in project. Alternately you can set "start without debugging" in the "Multiple startup projects" settings.

Hope this helps someone else down the line.